# Populate a form with the user detail after submitting the form, at /admin side

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm working on leave management system where a user submits this form -

```
from django import forms
from lrequests.models import Leave

class LeaveRequestForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        fields = ("department", "designation", "type_of_leave", "from_date", "to_date", "reporting_manager", "reason")
        model = Leave
```

whose model is -

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (('1','Earned Leave'),('2','Casual Leave'),('3','Sick Leave'),('4','Paid Leave'))
STATUS_CHOICES = ((1, 'Accepted'),(0, 'Rejected'),)
class Leave(models.Model):

    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    type_of_leave = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = CHOICES)
    from_date = models.DateField(help_text = 'mm/dd/yy')
    to_date = models.DateField(help_text = 'mm/dd/yy')
    reporting_manager = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = None, help_text = '0001_manager, 0002_manager')
    reason = models.CharField(max_length= 180)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    reason_reject = models.CharField(('reason for rejection'),max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The user doesn't fill the fields `name` and `employee_ID`, which were given at the time of signing up. These should automatically get filled in the admin site and db. I've tried and read documentation on [`ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) but couldn't come to the point. Can anyone please explain this topic in detail, am I heading in the correct direction or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CreateView (or FormView)

call the `get_initial()` something like this:

```
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['name'] = self.request.user.name
        initial['employee_ID'] = self.request.user.employee_ID
        return initial
```

I don't know if your usermodel has the properties name and employee ID, if not you need to get them from somewhere else.